# phpunit unit test a class accepted invoke argumant attributes

Tags: phpunit

I have this class `classToTest` that has an invoke method that accepts an argument, an array. So I need to test in a unit test with phpunit that this array has specific keys.

```
$data = [
     "items1" => 1,
     "items2" => ,
];

$pdf = (new classToTest())($data);
```

I tried to not pass items so that it can fail but some items are nullable.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What do you expect to happen? And what does the function in `classToTest` look like?

Comment: this class calls  callculatte the students test results and  the loops over them the calls another class to update theri records